# How can I trust Allah?

Tags: allah

Everybody says but your trust in him and everything would be ok, but I'm so scared to trust him.
I feel like I won't get what I want if I just seat there and do nothing.
And I have lost patience.

If only I can get a reply back from him, then I can relax.

I'm trying so hard to trust him, but idk anymore.

Comment: Related question: does not trusting Allah disqualify one from being muslim?

Comment: Your question is very broad, please go through lectures on renowned scholars, you will get guides, May Allah show you the right path.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PuXYxvIl_iU

Comment: @G.Bach Yes, indeed being a Muslim trasting in Allah is a must not a choice, and only the lack of faith can lead one to such a sin, trasting in allah does't mean you stay in the corner waiting fo miracles to happens, you have to do thing that make this stuff hapens while keeping trasting that allah will helps reaching your goals, may allah forgive as all

Answer (score 3):

> I feel like I won't get what I want if I just [sit] there and do nothing.

That's unsurprising.  Has anyone ever gotten anything by sitting there doing nothing?  This does not seem to be the kind of trust one should aim for:

> O Allah! I ask You for guidance, piety, chastity and self-sufficiency.  -- Prophet Muhammad, reported by Abdullah bin Mas'ud (source: http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/71)

We can trust in Allah while simultaneously seeking to do things ourselves.  Indeed, the Qur'an says we need to strive for our goals:

> And that there is not for man except that [good] for which he strives.  And that his effort is going to be seen, then he will be recompensed for it with the fullest recompense.  -- [Qur'an 53:39-41](https://quran.com/53:39)

We trust Allah to guide us to the straight path, and He may help us find the fortitude to walk it, but in the end, we're the ones who need to walk it.

> If they would only put their trust in Allah as they should, He would provide for them like he provides for the birds who fly out in the morning hungry and return fully satiated. -- Prophet Muhammad, narrated by Sunan al-Tirmidhī (2344) and Sunan Ibn Mājah (4164)
>
> The example of the bird going out in the morning shows us that one of the greatest expressions of faith and devotion is to take all practical steps to achieve our goals while at the same time placing our complete reliance upon Allah for the outcome (Al-Oadah, 2012).

(Sourced from: http://muslimsuccess.com/robins-trust-allah/)

Comment: "Tie your camel, then trust in Allah" comes to mind as well.